# How i can do this when user click on buyer role it will go to homepage and when user select seller role it will go to Dashboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> This is application Controller for devise

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  private
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:role])
  end
end
```

> signup form from devise and adding role

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>
```

> This is a role code

There is a problem when user select buyer on signup page it should go the homepage , when user select seller it should go to the selled dashboard

```
   <%= f.label :role %>
      <%= f.select :role, User.roles.keys %>

  Here is the submit button

<div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Sign up", data: {turbo: false} %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    
<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Comment: It looks like you are using the devise gem. I suggest looking into the device wiki: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-%28registration%29

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide much context about what you do in your controller when a user is signed up and how you build the form. Therefore I will just assume that it is a very basic form and all attributes are nested properly in the request and that the create action follows a simple scaffolding structure.

Then you basically only need to change where to redirect the user to depending on its role after the record was created.

```
# in controllers/users.rb
def create
  user = User.new(user_params)
  if user.save
    case user.role
    when 'user'
      redirect_to root_path
    when 'seller'
      redirect_to dashboard_path
    end
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

Comment: i just edit post kindly check and give me solution please